# Implement Angular 2 Material 2 Toolbar as a Module

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im attempting to learn how to use Angular 2 with Material 2 as we are using it in our project. I understand how to implement an md-toolbar as a component by creating the component and adding the component to the NgModule declarations. This is pretty straight forward. However I cannot figure out how to implement the toolbar as a component within a module. When I try to do so I receive the following error.

[image]

My code is as follows:

**Toolbar Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ToolbarComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  exports: [
    ToolbarComponent
  ]
})

export class ToolbarModule {}
```

**Toolbar Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})

export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Toolbar');
  }
}
```

**Toolbar Component HTML:**

```
<md-toolbar>
  <span>My Application Title</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

**App Module:**

```
// Application Dependencies 
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Application Modules
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ToolbarModule } from './modules/toolbar/toolbar.module';

// Application Components 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Application Pages
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './pages/about/about.component';

// Application Services
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { removeNgStyles, createNewHosts } from '@angularclass/hmr';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,

    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ToolbarModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
  hmrOnInit(store) {
    console.log('HMR store', store);
  }
  hmrOnDestroy(store) {
    let cmpLocation = this.appRef.components.map(cmp => cmp.location.nativeElement);
    // recreate elements
    store.disposeOldHosts = createNewHosts(cmpLocation);
    // remove styles
    removeNgStyles();
  }
  hmrAfterDestroy(store) {
    // display new elements
    store.disposeOldHosts();
    delete store.disposeOldHosts;
  }
}
```

**App Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../style/app.scss';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  url = 'https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack';

  constructor() {
    // Do something with api
  }
}
```

**App Component HTML:**

```
<header>
  <toolbar></toolbar>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

I feel like I have missed something simple but have not been able to figure it out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as this pattern of separating things into modules is common for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child components do not inherit the module imports of parent components. Because of that you have to import `MaterialModule.forRoot()` within `ToolbarModule`